# Is it possible to select a folder and upload all the files inside it in angular 9?

Tags: angular, file-upload

I would like to upload all the files in a local folder without having to select each files one by one.
Is it possible in angular 9?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) element you can easily get all the subfiles and subfolders of a selected folder.

This is an HTMLInputElement so of course you can integrate it into an Angular app or in whatever that contain HTML.

Here is an example of how to do it :

In your HTML template

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFolderSelected($event)" webkitdirectory multiple/>
```

In your Component

```
onFolderSelected(event){
    if (event.target.files.length > 0){
        let files = event.target.files;
    }     
}
```

Your `files` will contain all the subfiles that are in your folder and in the subfolders.

If you only want to keep the files in the folder you specify and not in the subfolders you can iterate over all the files to check if they are or not in a subfolder like that.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    if(!(files[i].webkitRelativePath.split('/').length > 2)){
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Here I split the webkitRelativePath by `/` because this string contain the entire path from your folder to the file. So if the file is directly in the folder you selected, the path will be as `folder/file`. In case the file is in a subfolder, the path will be as `folder/subfolder(s)/file` so automatically there will be more than 2 elements in the array generated by the split function.

Answer (score 0):

**webkitdirectory** element allows you to easily get all the files from folder and its subfolders.
But for **reading all files from Folders and its sub-folders** using **Drag and Drop**
is quite tricky.

You need to call **getDroppedFilesFromFolder(event: DragEvent)** inside your **Drag and Drop Zone** drop handler method dropHandler(event)

Below is sample angular code :

Your Drop Zone sample HTML code

```
 <div class="drop-zone" (drop)="dropHandler($event)">
```

Your typescript file method:

```
 public dropHandler(event){this.getDroppedFilesFromFolder(event).then((files)=>{// your logic here});}

   private getDroppedFilesFromFolder(event: DragEvent): Promise<any> {
    const dataTransfer: DataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    if (dataTransfer && dataTransfer.items) {
        return this.getDataTransferFiles(dataTransfer).then((_fileList) => {
            return Promise.resolve(_fileList);
        });
    }
}

private getDataTransferFiles(dataTransfer: DataTransfer): Promise<any[]> | Promise<[]> {
    const dataTransferFiles = [];
    const folderPromises = [];
    const filePromises = [];

    [].slice.call(dataTransfer.items).forEach((listItem: DataTransferItem) => {
        if (typeof listItem.webkitGetAsEntry === 'function') {
            const entry = listItem.webkitGetAsEntry();

            if (entry) {
                if (entry.isDirectory) {
                    folderPromises.push(this.traverseDirectory(entry));
                } else {
                    filePromises.push(this.getFile(entry));
                }
            }
        } else {
            dataTransferFiles.push(listItem);
        }
    });
    if (folderPromises.length) {
        const flatten = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []);
        return Promise.all(folderPromises).then((fileEntries) => {
            const flattenedEntries = flatten(fileEntries);
            // collect async promises to convert each fileEntry into a File object
            flattenedEntries.forEach((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {
                filePromises.push(this.getFile(fileEntry));
            });
            return this.handleFilePromises(filePromises, dataTransferFiles);
        });
    } else if (filePromises.length) {
        return this.handleFilePromises(filePromises, dataTransferFiles);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(dataTransferFiles);
}

private getFile(entry: FileEntry): Promise<IFile> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        entry.file((file) => {
            resolve(file);
        });
    });
}

private handleFilePromises(promises: any[], fileList: any[]): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.all(promises).then((files) => {
        files.forEach((file: File) => {
            fileList.push(file);
        });
        return fileList;
    });
}

private traverseDirectory(entry: any): Promise<any> {
    const reader = entry.createReader();

    // Resolved when the entire directory is traversed
    return new Promise((resolveDirectory) => {
        const iterationAttempts = [];
        const errorHandler = (): void => {};

        // Separate private method for reading directory entries recursively
        const readEntries = (): void => {
            reader.readEntries((batchEntries) => {
                if (!batchEntries.length) {
                    // Done iterating this particular directory
                    resolveDirectory(Promise.all(iterationAttempts));
                } else {
                    iterationAttempts.push(
                        Promise.all(
                            batchEntries.map((batchEntry) => {
                                if (batchEntry.isDirectory) {
                                    return this.traverseDirectory(batchEntry);
                                }
                                return Promise.resolve(batchEntry);
                            })
                        )
                    );
                    // Try calling readEntries() again for the same dir, according to spec
                    readEntries();
                }
            }, errorHandler);
        };

        // initial call to recursive entry reader function
        readEntries();
    });
}
```

Comment: Angular folder upload using drag and drop